# Unhide row in Database tool window

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I am currently experimenting with the database tool window in PhpStorm.

When right clicking a row header and selecting "hide", the column disappears. But I cannot find a way to unhide it.

Answer (score 3):

On the configure button, select the **Reset View** option.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This answer, and the picture link, was exactly what I was looking for, because the solution is unintuitive and under-documented. This works on phpstorm 2019.3. If one needs a reason for this newer answer, its because phpstorm has changed over the years

Answer (score 2):

At the top right corner click on settings icon and choose `Reset View` from dropdown menu
[image]

Comment: This works, but it would be even better, if i could toggle individual columns on and off. This approach only allows to reset all at once.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the options to hide and show the columns are in different places in the PhpStorm UI. But looking through several flaps I could finally find the option to show the columns.

After clicking on **Hide column**, we can reestablish this operation with **Show column**

- Structure
- Right click on some hidden/visible column
- Click on hide/show column

> We can also select the column and, type the space key to show it or hide it

[image: Show Column after having hidden them.]